# Characterize all pairs of integers $m$ and $n$ for which $\phi(mn)=\phi(n)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have found a solution here [Euler function $\phi(mn) = \phi(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186316/euler-function-phimn-phin) but I cannot fully understand. Given the formula $\varphi(n)=n\prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ I fail to see how $\varphi(mn)\geq \varphi(m)\cdot\varphi(n)$. Moreover, I need to be walked more slowly through the final steps.

Comment: For example, for any odd $\;n\;$ , you have $\;\phi(2n)=\phi(n)\;$ ...

Comment: If $m,n$ are coprime we have $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$. What changes if $m,n$ share a factor?